# django-tinymce modern theme

Tags: django, tinymce, tinymce-4, django-tinymce

I'm having issues getting the modern theme to work with django-tinymce. Both the simple and the advanced themes render correctly, but when I switch to the modern theme nothing renders and I get a 404 error for /static/tiny_mce/themes/modern/editor_template.js in the console

I am attempting to do all of this in the django admin. The error is coming from /static/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js which is interesting because I don't have anything installed in that directory. I'm using /static/js/tinymce as my `TINYMCE_JS_ROOT` in settings.py. When switching between simple and advanced theme, everything works correctly.

I've tried to copy a version of editor_template.js in the exact location it's looking, but I still get the 404. It's like it wipes out /static/tiny_mce if it exists and replaces it with something, but I can't figure out how/where it's getting that from.

I'm using an install of TinyMCE 4.1.3 from http://www.tinymce.com/download/download.php and django 1.6.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been struggling with TinyMCE recently, as well. I'm using TinyMCE v4 and Django 1.6. I went down the `django-tinymce`/`django-flatpages-tinymce` route because I had these working on another project. Some how it wasn't working for this new project. I did some research and decided to just go straight TinyMCE, no Django applications (eg, no `django-tinymce` or `django-flatpages-tinymce`).

This method cuts down on all configuration in Django, and it can be completely handled within the `tinymce.init` call. I found this much easier than dealing with Django's settings files, overriding models, etc. Just simply find the template you want TinyMCE to spice up and add the `init` call there.

The example here for full featured example really helped me:

http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/full.php

This use the modern theme...

I simply added this to whichever `change_form.html` template for whatever model I was needing the rich editor. For instance for flatpages:

```
admin/flatpages/flatpage/change_form.html
```

Or custom model in app:

```
admin/custom_app/model_name/change_form.html
```

I know this is exactly an answer to your question, but I think it's worth thinking about and might help you ultimately get what you need.

Also, I should note, it looks like only modern theme is available for TinyMCE v4:

http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Tutorial:Migration_guide_from_3.x

Comment: I ended up doing the same thing - got rid of django-tinymce and just went with straight tinyMCE. Maybe it's something that needs to be changed with the django-tinymce app

Comment: Cool, glad to hear it... If there aren't any other answers, it wouldn't hurt to accept the one I provided...