# django tinymce not showing rich textarea

Tags: python, django, forms, tinymce

My settings:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)
TINYMCE_JS_URL = os.path.join(MEDIA_ROOT, "js/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js")
TINYMCE_JS_ROOT = os.path.join(MEDIA_ROOT, "js/tiny_mce")
TINYMCE_DEFAULT_CONFIG = {
    'plugins': "table,spellchecker,paste,searchreplace",
    'theme': "advanced",
    'cleanup_on_startup': True,
    'custom_undo_redo_levels': 10,
}
TINYMCE_SPELLCHECKER = True
TINYMCE_COMPRESSOR = True
```

and my form:

```
class AnswerCreationForm(forms.ModelForm):

ans_body = forms.CharField(widget=TinyMCE(attrs={'cols': 80, 'rows': 30}))
class Meta:
    model = Answer 
    fields = ('ans_body',)
```

and in my view I have did  this:

```
<head>
    {{answer_form.media}}
</head>
<form action="{% url "answer-submit" question.id %}" method="get">{% csrf_token %}
{{answer_form.as_p}}
<input type="submit" value="Answer">
</form>
```

but its not displaying the rich text just displaying the normal text editor.

I have even tried:

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
tinymce.init({
    theme: "advanced",
    width: 300,
    height: 300,
    plugins: [
     "advlist autolink link image lists charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak      spellchecker",
     "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen insertdatetime media nonbreaking",
     "save table contextmenu directionality emoticons template paste textcolor"
   ],
   content_css: "css/content.css",
   toolbar: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | l      ink image | print preview media fullpage | forecolor backcolor emoticons", 
   style_formats: [
        {title: 'Bold text', inline: 'b'},
        {title: 'Red text', inline: 'span', styles: {color: '#ff0000'}},
        {title: 'Red header', block: 'h1', styles: {color: '#ff0000'}},
        {title: 'Example 1', inline: 'span', classes: 'example1'},
        {title: 'Example 2', inline: 'span', classes: 'example2'},
        {title: 'Table styles'},
        {title: 'Table row 1', selector: 'tr', classes: 'tablerow1'}
    ]
  }); 
 </script>

 </head>
<form action="{% url "answer-submit" question.id %}" method="get">{% csrf_token %}
{{answer_form.as_p}}
<input type="submit" value="Answer">
</form>
```

but also it doesnt show rich text editor?? How can I display it?? What am I doing wrong ??

Comment: check http://django-tinymce.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation.html that you have done all steps

Comment: I have done every step right and I ran test.. Its showing rich text in test..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This answer is kind of skirting the issue, but hopefully it helps you. It is the solution that I found for my projects.

I have troubles with django-tinymce as well, and I ended up not being able to solve the problem but found the solution using straight tinymce instead of the django-tinymce app. Here is the question that I asked: [django-tinymce modern theme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25188764/django-tinymce-modern-theme)

All you have to do is include this javascript on a page and it replaces the textareas with the RTE. Hopefully this works for what you need.

```
<script src="//tinymce.cachefly.net/4.1/tinymce.min.js"></script>
<script>
tinymce.init({selector:'textarea',
    plugins: [
        "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak",
        "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen",
        "insertdatetime media nonbreaking save table contextmenu directionality",
        "emoticons template paste textcolor colorpicker textpattern"
    ],
});</script>
```

Comment: How to use it in model form??

Comment: I had trouble also with django-tinymce. I used @awwester solution..and worked like a charm

Comment: Still experiencing this issue with `django-tinymce==3.5.0` but this solution worked for me. All my scripts are being loaded but for some reason the textarea is not initialised by tinymce.

Answer (score 1):

I know you solved your problem, but as I was looking to find the answer to solve my problem of not showing my desired stuff in the frontend, I reply to you:

you just need to filter in the frontend, so add like this in your template file:

```
{{ your_view_context.your_model_field | safe }}
```